# PL/SQL procedure successfully completed, but when I want to display Max(DEPARTMENT_ID), can anyone pls suggest?

Tags: plsql

Max(DEPARTMENT_ID), can anyone Please suggest

```
<set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
 v_max_deptno DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID%TYPE; 
 BEGIN
 SELECT Max(department_id)
 INTO v_max_deptno
 FROM   departments
 Where department_id = v_max_deptno;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The maximum department_id is: '|| v_max_deptno);
 END;/>
```

Comment: If you get an error, what is the error that you get?

Comment: remove the  where clause `Where department_id = v_max_deptno`

Answer (score 1):

This declaration:

```
v_max_deptno DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID%TYPE;
```

is for a local variable. Since you provide no default value and it is never assigned any value, it defaults to `NULL`.

This predicate in the SQL query:

```
Where department_id = v_max_deptno
```

means that the query should only return rows where the department_id is equal to the value in that variable. Since the variable is `NULL`, and since no value can equal `NULL`, the query returns no rows.

Since your query is based on a simple aggregate (`MAX`), the query returns without error. Since there were no rows, the `MAX` function returns `NULL` back into the same variable again.

For further assistance, you need to explain what the purpose of your code is and what value you expect to get. If you need the maximum department_id currently in the table across all rows, you would simply remove the `where` clause.

Note: if your purpose in finding the current maximum ID is to set the department_id for a new record, there are some other issues with this approach (to do with concurrent sessions) that you need to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't make much sense, as it is trying to find the `MAX(department_id)` (and put its value into the `V_MAX_DEPTNO` variable), while the same variable is used in the `WHERE` clause.

At the time of declaration, `V_MAX_DEPTNO` is NULL, it is NULL in the `WHERE` clause as well, and no department's ID is "equal" to NULL, so that query returns *nothing*.

If you initialized the `V_MAX_DEPTNO` (which is, of course, stupid), you'd get *something*:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_max_deptno   departments.department_id%TYPE := 20;
  3  BEGIN
  4     SELECT MAX (department_id)
  5       INTO v_max_deptno
  6       FROM departments
  7      WHERE department_id = v_max_deptno;
  8
  9     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('The maximum department_id is: ' || v_max_deptno);
 10  END;
 11  /
The maximum department_id is: 20

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

So the question is: what are you trying to do? In my opinion, the right way to do it is to remove this `WHERE` clause, i.e.

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_max_deptno   departments.department_id%TYPE := 20;
  3  BEGIN
  4     SELECT MAX (department_id)
  5       INTO v_max_deptno
  6       FROM departments;
  7
  8     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('The maximum department_id is: ' || v_max_deptno);
  9  END;
 10  /
The maximum department_id is: 40

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```